# Spring Boot - Not a managed type, Error creating bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, javabeans

I was wondering how can I fix these errors in my Spring Boot project, I created quite simple project with login/register based on Spring Security, but I don't know how to fix this stuff, I've tried all recommendations with same issues, but none of that helped me :(

Thanks in advance!

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'authController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'employeeRepository': Error creating bean with name 'employeeRepository' defined in com.artostapyshyn.personaldpslviv.model.repository.EmployeeRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Not a managed type: class com.artostapyshyn.personaldpslviv.model.entity.Employee
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:712) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:692) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:127) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:481) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1397) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:915) ~[spring-context-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.artostapyshyn.personaldpslviv.PersonaldpslvivApplication.main(PersonaldpslvivApplication.java:14) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeRepository' defined in com.artostapyshyn.personaldpslviv.model.repository.EmployeeRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Not a managed type: class com.artostapyshyn.personaldpslviv.model.entity.Employee
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1751) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1405) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:709) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.artostapyshyn.personaldpslviv.model.entity.Employee
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.JpaMetamodelImpl.managedType(JpaMetamodelImpl.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.managedType(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:496) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.managedType(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:77) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:69) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:246) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:211) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:194) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:81) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:317) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:279) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:229) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:113) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:132) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1797) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1747) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
```

All code from my project:

**Security configuration**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;
    
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService employeeDetailsService() {
        return new EmployeeDetailsServiceImpl();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(employeeDetailsService());
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        
        return authProvider;
    }

    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public void filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .requestMatchers("/users").authenticated()
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
                .usernameParameter("email")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/users")
                .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll();
    }
    
    
}
```

**Application controller**

```
@Controller
public class AuthController {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;
    
    @GetMapping("")
    public String viewHomePage() {
        return "home";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/register")
    public String showRegistrationForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("employee", new Employee());
        
        return "registration";
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/process_register")
    public String processRegister(Employee employee) {
        BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        String encodedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(employee.getPassword());
        employee.setPassword(encodedPassword);
        
        employeeRepository.save(employee);
        
        return "register_success";
    }

}
```

**Employee entity**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name = "employees")
public class Employee {

    @Id
   // @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;
    
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;
    
    @Column(name = "department")
    private String department;
    
    @Column(name = "phone_number")
    private String phoneNumber;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
    
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
}
```

**Repository**

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long>{
    @Query("SELECT u FROM Employee u WHERE u.department = :department")
    public Employee findByDepartment(String department);
}
```

**EmployeeDetails**

```
public class EmployeeDetails implements UserDetails {

    private Employee employee;
    
    public EmployeeDetails(Employee employee) {
        this.employee = employee;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return employee.getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return employee.getEmail();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
    
    public String getFullName() {
        return employee.getFirstName() + " " + employee.getLastName();
    }
```

**EmployeeDetailsService implementation**

```
@Service
public class EmployeeDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepo;
    
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String department) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Employee employee = employeeRepo.findByDepartment(department);
        if (employee == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found");
        }
        return new EmployeeDetails(employee);
    }
}
```

**Boot application**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class PersonaldpslvivApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PersonaldpslvivApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: @Reimeus As I said, I checked this topic, but none of that helped me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I managed to fix these errors, only by changing Spring Boot version, I had **3.0.2**, then I changed to **3.0.1** and it works!

Answer (score 1):

Your query in your repository should be like this:

```
@Query("SELECT u FROM Employee u WHERE u.department = ?1")
```

instead of this :

```
@Query("SELECT u FROM Employee u WHERE u.department = ?")
```

or you can change it to this :

```
@Query("SELECT u FROM Employee u WHERE u.department = :department ")
```

based on your function's parameter name

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've changed this, would be nice to hear what to do with exceptions

Comment: @Artostapyshyn it didn't fix your problem, Same exceptions also?

Comment: yeah, didn't help

Comment: well I don't know, Maybe spring boot is not scanning your classes, Also you need to clean your code a little bit its soo messy, especially in your SecurityConfig